# CameraX reinitialize every time

Tags: android, android-fragments, camera, android-camerax

I have a question related to android camerax architecture. I am using preview view and it works perfect. The problem is related to transaction between fragments. Fragment 1 has previewView. When I switch to fragment2 and come back to fragment1 I bind previewview again so it first black screen appears then the preview appears on screen. I dont want to see the black screen. Are there any solutions for that problem ?

Answer (score 1):

The camera's lifecycle is controlled by the `LifecycleOwner` you use when calling `bindtoLifecycle()`. So if you want to keep the camera running even when the screen that contains the viewfinder is no longer visible to the user, you can just use a `LifecycleOwner` that doesn't stop when you switch fragments, e.g. the hosting Activity's lifecycle.

This will keep the camera running though even when it's not needed, which may consume more device resources than needed, and may cause privacy concerns for users (e.g. if the device shows an indicator that the camera is running, even when they aren't directly using it in the app).